# If I have the dependency information for Maven, how do I determine the fully qualified name to include within my source code import statement? [Java]

Tags: java, maven, import, terminal, dependencies

I am looking to leverage TeamRapids API for theGuardian news information and they provided the dependency information to include within the POM file (included below). However, I believe I still need to import the library within my source code and I cannot locate the fully qualified name for it(i.e. import mashape.unirest). How do I determine the library to import?

Note: I am not using any IDE. I code within Notepad and compile via Terminal.
Edit: Sorry not Terminal, I am executing via Windows command line...not Linux..

Dependency Info

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
          <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

Example of how to call it

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://guardianmikilior1v1.p.rapidapi.com/getEditions")
    .header("x-rapidapi-host", "Guardianmikilior1V1.p.rapidapi.com")
    .header("x-rapidapi-key", "704b8fcc46msh46ce303d0171e1ep101c61jsn44bf35571958")
    .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .asString();
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Check your $HOME/.m2/repository/con/mash ape/unirest/1.4.9 directory. You can view the contents of the jar therein to learn the full class name(s). But the documentation should help too if you can find it...

Comment: Note that a jar is just a ZIP file with specific contents, so an ordinary ZIP utility will also work (I usually use `unzip -l`).

Comment: Thank you both! Found the classes needed! It compiles but won't execute as it throws the below error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mashape/unirest/http/exceptions/UnirestException" I imported this class fully but still it won't run?

Comment: @ZishanAmin You cannot just run a normal jar without specifying the classpath, i.e. the list of jars you need. If you want to avoid that, you can build an executable jar with the maven assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin.

Comment: BTW You make your life much easier if you use Eclipse or IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java `jar` tool to see all the classes in the jar.

**Solution 1:**
open this path in command prompt/ terminal. $HOME/.m2/repository/JAR_FILE_DIRECTORY. and type the below

```
jar -tvf unirest-java-1.4.9.jar
```

> -t  list table of contents for archive
>
> -v  generate verbose output on standard output
>
> -f  specify archive file name

**Solution 2:**

Extract the contents in the jar file.

```
jar -xf unirest-java-1.4.9.jar
```

> -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
>
> -f  specify archive file name